# How to create SP site view to see all the tasks assigned to subordinates

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Can you please advise how to simply create a SP site view where a supervisor could see all of the tasks that are assigned to his subordinates to control status and see how busy they are.

It’s important that a manager could see or choose only members of his team.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's nothing in the view initially that will allow you to filter this information. I'd suggest creating a Manager field on the task list, and then developing a simple SharePoint Designer Workflow that looks up the manager for you, and inserts that value into your newly created Manager field. After you do this, you can create filters off that value, including a Manager View where "Manager=[Me]." Note this isn't changing who has access to what records -it's just facilitating the view so that data can be filtered to a specific manager.

How you grab the manager in your workflow depends on whether you're creating a SharePoint 2010 or 2013 Workflow. [This blog](http://spmavericks.com/2014/10/30/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-find-manager-alternative/) does a good job covering how you accomplish this in both scenarios.

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Thanks Matt. This solution materializes the data at the moment when modification is performed, which results in difficulties in the future, when a new manager comes, or the structure of the company changes.
Secondly, as you pointed out, this is only a matter of filtering, and not security. And breaking inheritance and materialization for each person individually can also result in problems with performance in the future.
I’m wondering how the ready-made solutions like K2, Nintex or WEBCON restrict access and visibility of elements on the go (not through materialization).